# How would I go about programmatically capturing internal audio?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, audio-recording, waveform

I'm trying to create a windows application, preferably in .NET, that performs waveform analysis and acoustic fingerprinting on incoming internal audio. By 'internal audio' I mean the sound that plays through my speakers, for instance, when I watch a youtube video or play an mp4 file. How would I go about capturing this internal audio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for Naudio. Although it does not have "internal audio" you could just load the mp3 or audio URL link. Another library that is very similar is cscore.

- [NAudio](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio)
- [CSCore](https://github.com/filoe/cscore)

Here is an NAudio example

```
WaveIn waveInStream;
WaveFileWriter writer;
waveInStream = new WaveIn(44100,2);
writer = new WaveFileWriter(outputFilename, waveInStream.WaveFormat);
waveInStream.DataAvailable += new EventHandler<WaveInEventArgs>(waveInStream_DataAvailable);
waveInStream.StartRecording();

void waveInStream_DataAvailable(object sender, WaveInEventArgs e)
{
   writer.WriteData(e.Buffer, 0, e.BytesRecorded);
}
```

Comment: Maybe you could show some simple examples on how to use these. It would help a lot to other users who could stumble upon this question. Just linking to some library is not very descriptive in every case.

Comment: Hey, I'm familiar with NAudio. I'm specifically trying to capture streaming audio as it plays though. Any way I might be able to do that?

Comment: Yes, you could try using `waveInStream = new WasapiLoopbackCapture();`